# Git says it allegedly ignores files but actually adds them

Tags: git

Given a git repository that has a `.gitignore` pointing towards `bar/foo/file` adding that file prints it fails adding them – it should require forcing through `-f` – while at the same time actually adding them.
More precisely the following command and its outputs are confusing:

```
$ git add bar/foo/file       
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
bar
hint: Use -f if you really want to add them.
hint: Turn this message off by running
hint: "git config advice.addIgnoredFile false"
$ git diff --cached
diff --git a/bar/foo/file b/bar/foo/file
index d00491f..0cfbf08 100644
--- a/bar/foo/file
+++ b/bar/foo/file
@@ -1 +1 @@
-1
+2
```

Note that the last command (`git diff`) should have no output if no file was changed.

To better retrace this, consider these commands:

```
$ cd $(mktemp -d)
$ git init
$ mkdir -p bar/foo
$ echo 1 > bar/foo/file
$ git add .
$ git commit -m 1
$ echo bar > .gitignore
$ git add .
$ git commit -m gi
$ echo 2 > bar/foo/file
$ git add foo/bar/file
$ git status
```

Is this desired bevahiour? Is this a bug?

Comment: Once a file is being tracked, `.gitignore` does not affect it. Desired behavior.

Comment: Bu the `hint` message is indeed misleading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file was *already* tracked. I agree the hint is wrong, you've found a corner case the newbie-helper logic didn't anticipate. I'd recommend `git config advice.addignoredfile false`.